# Use groovy-variable in Jenkins-Batchscript

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I have this pipeline-script:

```
script {
    def resultFile = "logs/Resharper-Warnings.out.xml"
    bat (script:
        '''
            set PlotFrameworkVersion=v4.5.1
            set ReferencePath='C:/lib'
            call ".../InspectCode.exe" "Path/To/My.sln" -a -o="${resultFile}"
        '''
    )
                        
    recordIssues(
        qualityGates: [[threshold: 1, type: 'TOTAL', unstable: true]], 
        tools: [resharperInspectCode(pattern: "${resultFile}")]
    )
}
```

As you can see I want to use the variable `resultFile` within both the `recordIssues`-step as well as the `bat`-step. When I execute it, I get the following log:

```
Inspection report was written to D:\Workspace\${resultFile}
```

so the variable isn´t expanded correctly. The `recorsIssues`-step however does parse the variable, as seen in the log:

```
Searching for all files in 'D:\Workspace' that match the pattern 'logs/Resharper-Warnings.out.xml'
```

So how do I use the variable correctly within my bat-step?

Answer (score 0):

It´s just about concatenating strings in groovy, which we can achieve using `+`. I ended up with this which isn´t the neatest way but it gets its job done:

```
''' set PlotFrameworkVersion=v4.5.1
    set ReferencePath='C:/lib'
    call ".../InspectCode.exe" "Path/To/My.sln" ''' + "-a -o=${resultFile}"
```